# Confusion about JavaScript execution context and hoisting

Tags: javascript, javascript-engine

I know that there are two phases when running a JavaScript code: creation phase and execution phase.

1. Creation phase passes through all arguments that were passed into the function and creates *argument* object. Then, the code is scanned for function and variable declarations. For each function and variable, a property is created in the *Variable Object*. Each "function" property is pointing to the function, and each variable is set to undefined. Scope chain and *this* variable are also created and defined respectively, but that isn't involved in my question.
2. Execution phase - the code is running line by line.

That explains the next code:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo1");
}

foo();

function foo() {
    console.log("foo2");
}
```

Where output in the console is:

```
foo2
```

And that makes sense, because the code is scanned at first, and then executed in the second phase.

However, if I had three .js files declared in an HTML file, like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="script1.js"></script>
        <script src="script2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where script.js, script1.js, and script2.js looks like this, respectively

script.js:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo1");
}
```

script1.js:

```
foo();
```

script2.js:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo2");
}
```

The output in the console is:

```
foo1
```

And I expected foo2.

Why are different files handled differently? I thought that engine scans through **ALL** included .js files creates execution context object, and then execute functions. Basically, I thought that there isn't any difference if JavaScript function (a.k.a. objects) are in different files rather than in a single file.

Thank you for any explanations.

Comment: The imported script blocks are executed as soon as they're fetched, so the second block runs before the third one runs.

Comment: I understand that, but shouldn't all scripts together act like a single script?

Comment: @Coelacanth no.

Comment: You can add new `<script>`s at any time, so how long should it wait before executing? forever?

Comment: @trincot agree to the dupe vote, however the answers there are not that helpful

Comment: I've seen that scripts are executed as soon as they are fetched, I was just looking for a detailed answer about how the engine does it

Comment: You just assumed wrongly when you wrote *"I thought that engine scans through ALL included .js files"*. There's not much else to it.